# Why my windows os was recovered to Ubuntu through dell recovery?

Tags: dell, data-recovery

I am using Windows 10. When I am into the bios setup of my pc,  I don't  know what happened (I Might have pressed any key) my pc(dell) started recovering to Ubuntu and I let that happen. Can I know why it happened like that? My windows was gone now.  Is it because my windows license has expired?

Now when ever I restart my pc it's showing like "preparing automatic repair" and then "diagnosing your pc" and finally an error that it cannot diagnise and showing two options shutdown or advances options. In advanced options after clicking on "use a device" and then clicking on "Ubuntu" I was able to log into the system(Ubuntu) ...

In Ubuntu I cannot connect to the WiFi also. No network  setting was editable. I don't know what to do. What should I do to recover to my windows 10?

My pc :  Dell inspiron 3558

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your PC model. I guess it is a laptop that shipped with Ubuntu? What do you mean by "all the data was into Ubuntu"? Where are the pictures you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hidden partition on your system where Dell put an ISO into of the version of the operating system that originally was on that system (in your case Ubuntu).

Your operating system has a couple of function keys during boot set to do something special. Enter the BIOS for instance. And one to restore to factory settings. In GRUB it is a special line:

[image]

Mind though that, for this to work from Ubuntu, you need to do more than just that. [From the dell site](http://www.dell.com/support/article/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/how12105/how-to-perform-a-factory-reset-on-a-computer-with-the-dell-oem-ubuntu-1404-and-1604-linux-developer-edition-installed?lang=en):

[image]

You will also need to confirm the restore.

> Is it because my windows license has expired?

No, it is because of an action you did.

How Windows does this is not up to us to answer ;)

Comment: Thank you  rinzwind.  But the problem is I was not able to connect to WiFi in the current Ubuntu. It is showing settings but not editable. What should I do? Connect an ether net cable? BTW if I go through the restore, would I loose all my files?

Comment: had the same issue with a hp envy the other day; find out vendor and device id. search online and use a cable to download and update ;)

Comment: Even ethernet cable is not being recognized... The network manager icon is also not available in the menu bar..